# How to get connection to elasticsearch server in local network inside ddev / Docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, ddev

How is it possible to get a connection to a Elasticserver instance, which is in the local network from inside of a running ddev / Docker container?

I have a ddev instance running. And off course I can use Elasticserver as ddev extension inside of the ddev container. Everything is working fine in thuis mode. But what I also need is to connecet inside of my ddev container a Elasticserver connection, which is in my local network as native Elasticserver installation as well.

All I found is the setup for to connection something from outside of the conntainer into a service which is running in the ddeb Docker container

Something like this:

```
web_extra_exposed_ports:
 - container_port: 3000
    http_port: 9998
    https_port: 9999
```

And the connection via https://.ddev.site:9999. Is there a way to do like this, but in Opposite direction?

Comment: I assume you're saying you are running Elasticsearch on the host side and you want DDEV's web container to connect to it? This requires two things:
1. The elasticsearch server must bind to all network interfaces (0.0.0.0)
2. You should use `host.docker.internal` to connect to it.  The default elasticsearch port is 9200, so you would connect to `host.docker.internal:9200` in that case. Try it out with just `ddev exec curl http://host.docker.internal:9200` and see what happens.